# C# Override OnValidating to support null value but breaks Data Binding

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a CustomTextBox which inherits from TextBox and overwrites the OnValidating method to allow empty strings.  CustomTextBox is bound to Property Price in Domain.

```
public class CustomTextBox
{
    protected override void OnValidating(...)
    {  
       if(Text=="") 
       {
           Text = null;
           return;
       }
       base.OnValidating(e);
    }
}
public class Domain
{
    public System.Nullable<decimale> Price
    { ... }
}
```

All works well except that this prevents users froming setting Price to null. `Text=null;` did not propogate to the domain object.  Is there a way to reset Price back to null when user clears out the TextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Binding to propagate values to the domain object, then you should put this logic in the [Parse event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.parse.aspx) instead.

```
// Add binding
var b = new Binding("Text", myDataSource, "BoundProperty");
b.Parse += OnNullableTextBindingParsed;
myTextBox.DataBindings.Add(b);


// Sample parse handler
private void OnNullableTextBindingParsed(object sender, ConverterEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value == String.Empty) e.Value = null;
}
```